# Using Excel VBA to automate form filling in Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, ui-automation

I want to take values from an excel sheet and store them in an array. I then want to take the values from the array and use them to fill the web form.

I have managed to store the values in the array and I have managed to get VBA to open Internet Explorer (IE)

The code runs and no errors appear, but the text fields are not being populated, nor is the button being clicked

(The debugger points to `[While .Busy]` as the error source, located in the `WITH` block)

How do I go about filling the form (that has a total of 3 text boxes to fill)?

There is also a drop down menu that I need to choose a value from, but I need to fill the text boxes prior to moving on to that part of the task.

```
Sub CONNECT_TO_IE()
the_start:   
Dim ie As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object




acct = GET_CLIENT_NAME()
name = GET_CODE()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate ("<<my_website>>")
   ie.FullScreen = False

    On Error Resume Next
       Do
       DoEvents
       If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       ie.Quit
       Set ie = Nothing
       GoTo the_start:
       End If
       Loop Until ie.readystate = 4

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

ie.Document.getElementbyid("<<field_1>>").Value = "PPP"
ie.Document.getElementbyid("<<field_2>>").Value = "PPP"
ie.Document.getElementbyid("<<field_3>>").Click


Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: There's no `While .Busy` or `With` block in your posted code.  Still , just calling `Navigate` and then waiting ten seconds should be enough to load the page.  If your code still doesn't work even when the page is loaded, there's not much we can do without a URL or the source HTML.

Comment: You may also need to .Focus the element first.

Comment: @QHarr , what will that do?

Comment: Sometimes you need to Focus an input element in order to add a value.

Comment: @TimWilliams , Here is the field I want to fill 
    [<INPUT id=accountCode maxLength=32 name=accountCode>].

Comment: @QHarr , can you show me syntax? I wouldn't know where to use that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Turns out the reason this wasn't working is because there are some settings in the HTML of the site that do not allow for the automation to occur, so any code versions I had were correct but they were doomed to fail. So you were correct in that regard @TimWilliams.

I know this because the website I was trying to access is on a secure server/virtual machine. I edited the code to fill in the google search bar and it did not work on the virtual machine however when I ran the same code locally, it worked fine.

Comment: In your previous answer, you had mentioned that code is working find on local machine. If you mean that there is no issue with the code posted in the original post then i suggest you to mark your last answer as an answer to close this thread.